# Android Studio fails to clean project

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio is creating strange files, which cannot be deleted.

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.`

> Unable to delete directory: F:\VWA2\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\4\uk\co

[image: The files android studio created and cannot be deleted]

These are the files. My question is, why they are even created and how this can be fixed.

Thank you!

Comment: Its really strange text. Delete the folder manually and try again.

Comment: Isn't your app currently running ?
It looks to be a temporary folder used for instantrunning compilation

Comment: Actually I can't rename or delete the files with the windows file explorer. This is because of the strange characters. Is it possible with the command line? Or do I need Linux?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/72280/cant-delete-folder-in-windows-7/72296#72296)

Comment: @Dominik105 What is your current font set for windows?

Comment: Just tried this, and Linux command line, both cannot delete the files. The font is standard for German language